# ArcMap - how to count polygons after intersection

Tags: arcmap, spatial-analyst

I'm trying to count buildings that are in high risk in flooded areas. How can I see number of houses where flooded areas exist?

I extracted raster by mask, reclassified and converted raster to polygon that gave me water in shapefile. Then I created buffer to increase area of houses by 2 meters. Now I would like to have number of houses (buffers) that intersect with water, but unfortunately after using Intersect tool, I have overlapped areas shown as next ones.

Comment: select by location? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) instead of Intersect. With the Search Radius parameter you can specify a "buffer", so no need to buffer either:

[image]

In the example I only have one flooded area. If you have more than one you will get many rows in the output table. You can summarize total Count with Summary statistics tool or by right-clicking column - Statistics.

Comment: Great! I totaly forgot about this tool. Thank you.